# Need help: Automatically refresh a page (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a test application that has a subscription. The subscription expires and I have a controller that handles the renew subscription(I know it's not good practice. I hired a cheap freelancer to do it and I don't really know how to program). The only way I know how to trigger a controller is with a link. I have a variable called 'days_til_expire' that will count down to zero.

Main Question: Is there a way to automatically trigger a refresh that will activate the controller I need. I'm thinking:

```
if days_till_expire == 0
  page refresh to controller#renew
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Wayne's answer:

Whenever user performs a "restricted" action (click to watch a video or whatever it is that your app hides behind the paywall), check subscription status and redirect to renew page if it's expired.

No need to bother with page refreshes. Unless, of course, your app has rich client-side UI (meaning, lots of javascript).

Comment: The main problem is we have a lot of links and each subscription is dependent on each user. (each user sets own subscription, each user can subscribe to each user and multiple subscription types). So I was asking if I can put it in an if statement that checks if it's zero then just refresh. the page with the controller active. Thanks for the help by the way. I'm not really a programmer and this  thing is just duct tape together (I'll learn to program and fix it later. right now I just want it out).

Comment: Also we use our own currency that we need to access within the application. (I can access currency in model but not in a controller... it's very confusing and messed up...)

Comment: Also it needs to be done automatically without user clicking anything (that's why I need instant refresh).

Comment: @Jakxna360: well, my advice is to seek professional help. It'll cost you some money, but it'll be the quickest way.

Comment: Are you available : )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trigger the link, you can use polling to check if expired or not, if expired, use js to redirect user.

Comment: The problem I have Is I don't really know JavaScript. If you can be a little bit more descriptive that would be awesome. Thank you for the help : )

Comment: @Jakxna360: you can get another developer and show him this post. He'll know what to do. Even if Wayne were to write the full code for you, you still can have troubles integrating it into your site.

Answer (score 0):

To further `@Sergio Tulentsev`'s answer, which is further to `@Wayne Chu`'s answer (answer-ception?????), this is something called [authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization), and can be handled entirely in the backend.

Simple implementation:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def expired?
      # logic for whether subscription has expired
   end
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authorized?

   private

   def authorized
      if current_user.expired?
         redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your Subscription has Expired"
      end
   end
end
```

This will fire every single time your user browses to a controller which inherits from the `ApplicationController` (`BlogsController < ApplicationController`).

--

A more integrated approach (instead of having to call a method every single time you browse to a controller) would be to validate against specific objects (using [`Pundit`](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)):

```
class PostPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def update?
    user.subscribed?
  end
end
```

The above would be accompanied by a daily process which would cycle through your users, and see if their subscription is valid. If not, it should set a value in the `users` db, which will then allow you to validate off it.

I've not used Pundit a lot, so the above code would need tweaking a lot. The most basic type of authorization is with roles. The alternative is object-orientated authorization, which will check against the object rather than the user.

---

If you need "professional help", and if you have a big budget, go to http://anadea.info (I have absolutely no affiliation with them); I worked with them in 2012 and is the reason I've been working with Rails ever since; top quality company.

Don't do it if you don't want to spend $5k+ though, it's not worth it.

[image]